# What is the best Micro Atx motherboard for my build with only 2 ram slots and an M.2 SSD slot?

Tags: motherboard

My concern is, I am not sure if the boards i'm looking at is compatible with the Ryzen 5 2600.

I am mainly using my computer for games and work so I think I do not need more than 2 ram slots and only plan to get 16gb of ram. Also definitely, needing a good M.2 NVME SSD slot

The build:

CPU: Ryzen 5 2600

RAM: 2 pcs of. 8gb ddr4 2666 Kingston HyperX Fury Black (16gb)

PSU: Seasonic S12II (650w)

GPU: Gigabyte RX 570 4gb

Storage: Samsung 970 EVO 500GB - NVMe PCIe M.2 2280 SSD (MZ-V7E500BW)

Answer (score 1):

Any B450, X470, or X570 motherboard will work with your Ryzen 5 2600. In addition, you could flash the BIOS of a B350 or X370 board, although getting one of the first three chipsets will mean out-of-box compatibility. I personally like ASUS boards, although Asrock, Gigabyte, and MSI tend to make decent boards as well.

Here's a couple recommendations off of the top of my head, but be sure to do some research to see which boards meet your needs and price point best.

- MSI B450M Pro-VHD Max
- ASUS B450M-PLUS TUF Gaming
- Gigabyte B450 AORUS M
- ASRock X570M PRO4